# Efficiently apply SciPy optimization methods to arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, scipy

Equation `f(x, a, b)` below requires an iterative solution, for which I am using one of the SciPy optimisation methods ([`brentq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html)), which is essentially calculating the value of `x` for which `f(x, a, b) = 0`.

However, I need to use array inputs for `a` and `b`, and these arrays are very large (e.g. could have 1-100 million elements).

What is the most efficient/fastest way to do this with SciPy/NumPy? At present, I am resorting to *for loops* as per below, but this becomes slow with my actual underlying equations (not shown). Note that each row in the arrays is independent of others.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
    
# function to solve (simplified)
def f(x, a, b): 
    return (a/x)**0.25 * (x**0.5) - b*x 

# array size
N = 10000000 

# example input arrays from which 'a' and 'b' are taken
# (in reality values come from other complex functions)
A = np.linspace(1, 500, N) 
B = np.linspace(0.1, 1, N)

# solution using brentq
results = [optimize.brentq(f, 1e10, 1000, args=(a, b)) 
           for a, b in zip(A, B)]
results
```

Comment: These iterative `scipy` solvers don't allow you to run multiple scenarios in a "vectorized" fashion.  That is, each solution is optimized (in terms of steps and so on) for one set of scalar (a,b) arguments.  Multiprocessing on a many core machine is probably the only way to speed this up.

Comment: Thanks - just looking at the optimize.newton docs (an alternative to brentq) and it seems to imply some kind of vectorized solution is possible, taking arrays (see link below). What do you make of that? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html

Comment: Update, just found this, as of v1.2.0 "scipy.optimize.newton can now accept a scalar or an array" https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.2.0.html

Comment: Have you tried with: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html ? Maybe I’m misunderstanding, but it seems to me your problem can be setup as a system of equations with n “x” variables and a, b scalars. Not sure fsolve can handle 1 million equations but maybe a few thousand at the time?

Comment: @Infinity77 'a' and 'b' are variables (and also functions of 'x') and are actually arrays of length 'n', just like 'x' is. I have tried fsolve, but so far have found it is quite a bit slower, even though it does seem to accept array inputs for both 'x' and also 'a' and 'b'. I am using scipy v1.1.0 so perhaps need to check using a more updated version. The optimize.newton route may be the most promising in terms of speed as per previous link.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, [`newton`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html) is vectorized to find the root for all parameter values in the arrays `A` and `B` in the same call.

However, `newton` uses Newton's method (or similar), so you can't really constrain the search. This is important for the provided function, because the function is not real-valued for all real `x`. As a bracketing root-finder, [`brentq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html) will not try to evaluate the function outside the provided bracket. However, it is not vectorized as `newton` is.

SciPy does not offer a public, vectorized, bracketing root-finder at this time, but it does have a private one in SciPy 1.12, which will likely turn into a public one "shortly", hopefully with support for alternative array backends (e.g. CuPy) via the Array-API.

There is no official support for use of private functions, and the location of the function will almost certainly change before SciPy 1.13, but for now:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
    
# function to solve (simplified)
def f(x, a, b): 
    return (a/x)**0.25 * (x**0.5) - b*x 

# array size
N = 1000

# example input arrays from which 'a' and 'b' are taken (in reality values come from other complex functions)
A = np.linspace(1, 500, N) 
B = np.linspace(0.1, 1, N)

# solution using _chandrupatla
res = optimize._zeros_py._chandrupatla(f, 1, 1000, args=(A, B))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(A, res.x)
```

[image]

As you can see from the timing, it certainly takes advantage of a vectorized callable:

```py
%timeit optimize._zeros_py._chandrupatla(f, 1, 1000, args=(A[0], B[0]))
# 2.17 ms ± 221 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit optimize._zeros_py._chandrupatla(f, 1, 1000, args=(A, B))
# 3.55 ms ± 157 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```